# Passing component as a prop in react native

Tags: react-native

In order to make a customize-able component, what should I do to pass component as a prop in another component.

I have a header component which may be customized depending on current pages actions.

For example, for autocomplete search, I may have a header component like this:

[image]

On another case, for trip search result, I may have a header component like this: [image]

I want build to a component that will receive a component as a prop and will render it to the current component. What is the best way to do this in react-native way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass a component as a prop or as child. The first way is this one:

```js
export default class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <PageComponent header = {<Header title = {".."}/>}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default class PageComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                {this.props.header}
                <View>
                    ...
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The second way is:

```js
export default class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <PageComponent>
                    <Header title = {".."}/>
                </PageComponent>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default class PageComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                {this.props.children}
                <View>
                    ...
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thanks, it was so simple even to think around.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to send send the componet as the prop as my app is showing `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: @SayokMajumder when you do like the answer say to do ( use the prop within a `{}` like `{this.props.header}`), and your component is a function, you must provide the header as `<MyComponent header={<Header />} {...} />`. You are probably missing `<` and `/>` around the Headercomponent.

Comment: What if , if we want to pass some thing to {this.props.chindren} ?